# Upgrading my system.web.extensions to 4.5

Tags: .net, dll, .net-4.5, .net-assembly, system.web.extensions

My system.web.extensions in the assembly is version 3.5.0.0 but I have .NET 4.5 installed. Is there a way for me to get my system.web.extensions to version 4.5.0.0 ?

Comment: Is your project targeting 3.5?

Comment: No it is targeting 4.5